# Como editar a margem do popover do bootstrap em css ou js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap, popover

Boa noite pessoal, estou implementando um popover na minha página, porém estou fazendo isso dentro de uma table que esta dentro de um jumbotron, o problema ocorre das 3 primeiras linhas onde o popover aparece distante do  onde ele deveria aparecer, a minha intenção é descobrir como alvejar ou "targetar" em css, ou descobrir como alterar em js e css este posicionamento errado.

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
})
```

```css
.jumbotron .container i{
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:120px;
    color:white;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;

}

.jumbotron p{
    
    color:white;
}
.jumbotron table{
    
    color:white;
} 



div .jumbotron{
        height:361px;
        border-radius:12px;
        background-color:#6de073;
```

```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
          <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-4">Plug seu celular na moda</h1>
            <p>Atendimento das 10:00 às 22:10 de Segunda-feira à Sábado!
            <p>
            <table style="width:100%">
                <th data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Politicas</th>
                <th data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Serviços</th>
                <th data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Informação</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Formas de Pagamento</td>
                <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Prazo de Troca</td>
                <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Troca de Películas</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Descontos</td>
                <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Políticas de Troca</td>
                <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Manutenção</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Sorteios</td>
                <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Regulamento de Trocas</td>
                <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Encomendas</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Fornecedores</td>
                <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Reembolso</td>
                <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Atendimento ao Cliente</td>
              </tr>
            </table>    
          </div>
        </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Segue o código abaixo:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer isso tem que alterar o comportamento do *popover* via jQuery de uma forma meio radical.

Como o *popover* é criado de forma dinâmica, o código abaixo sobrepõe os estilos quando o mouse é passado na primeira coluna da tabela:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
   $("table tr td:first-child, table th:first").on("mouseover", function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      setTimeout(function(){
         $(".popover")
         .removeClass("bs-popover-top bs-popover-bottom")
         .addClass("bs-popover-right")
         .css({
            "top": $this.offset().top - ($(".popover").height()/2)+10+"px",
            "left": $this.offset().left+100+"px",
            "transform":"translate3d(0,0,0)"
         })
         .attr("x-placement","right")
         .find(".arrow")
         .css({
            "top": $(".popover").height()/2-12+"px",
            "left":"-9px"
         });
      }, 10);
   }).on("mouseleave", function(){
      $(".popover").remove();
   });
});
```

```css
.jumbotron .container i{
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:120px;
    color:white;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;

}

.jumbotron p{
    
    color:white;
}
.jumbotron table{
    
    color:white;
} 



div .jumbotron{
        height:361px;
        border-radius:12px;
        background-color:#6de073;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
 <div class="container">
   <h1 class="display-4">Plug seu celular na moda</h1>
   <p>Atendimento das 10:00 às 22:10 de Segunda-feira à Sábado!
   <p>
   <table style="width:100%">
       <th data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Politicas</th>
       <th data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Serviços</th>
       <th data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Informação</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Formas de Pagamento</td>
       <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Prazo de Troca</td>
       <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Troca de Películas</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Descontos</td>
       <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Políticas de Troca</td>
       <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Manutenção</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Sorteios</td>
       <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Regulamento de Trocas</td>
       <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Encomendas</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Fornecedores!">Fornecedores</td>
       <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Reembolso</td>
       <td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Atendimento ao Cliente</td>
     </tr>
   </table>    
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Estranho posso ver claramente a sua solução funcionando quando executo o código aqui no stackoverflow, porém quando executo esse código aqui ele não altera nada, qual séra o motivo? estou quebrando a cabeça tentando fazer funcionar

Comment: @PublioElon Fiz uma pequena modificação no script. Eu estava usando bootstrap 4, que dá uma grande diferença para o 3, que é o que vc está usando.

Comment: to usando o 4 também veja pelo link o nome do arquivo: <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: @PublioElon Verdade.Se possível, faz um JSFiddle e posta todo o seu HTML para que eu possa dar uma olhada. As vezes tem outra coisa causando conflito.

Comment: Ok eu coloquei no jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f4Lp5o2d/ o HTML ta um pouco zoado, mas a parte do conteúdo do jumbotron/popover onde esta o problema esta exatamente da forma que aparece pra mim

Comment: @PublioElon Acho que agora vai. Tinha um problema: O script que eu fiz tinha que estar dentro do document ready tb.

Comment: nice demais mano! deu certinho!